# Main statement for sending information from HTTP server to GCM(Google cloud Messaging)

Tags: java, php, web-services, jetty, google-cloud-messaging

This document (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) describes the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) HTTP connection server. Connection servers are the Google-provided servers that take messages from the 3rd-party application server and sending them to the device.
Consider i prepared a HTTP server for GCM based on this document. how i can send information to GCM with PHP? should i use POST method? how? or it doesn't related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should send a POST request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send. It doesn't matter which language you are using in your server. PHP would work just fine.

Comment: thanks. 
is this correct?
<form action=" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" method="post">
{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
</form>

Comment: @BagherS You also need some headers for the request to be accepted.